# How do keyless ignition fobs charge?

Tags: honda, keyless-entry

I have a 2013 Honda Accord with a keyless entry system and can't figure out how to charge the keyless entry fob. I've looked in the manual and can't find anything about it. I asked the dealer and they don't know either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

All the fobs I have had contain a small watch battery. They seem to last longer than I keep the car. I have had them last 7 or 8 years.

Comment: Agreed, the battery should last a very long time. Most batteries are replaced by simply splitting the remote.. Look around the edges and you will typically find a notch to place a coin that you can trust to pry it open

Comment: Yesterday I replaced the batteries of my Saab keys. The manual stipulated that I then push open four times or less (to get it recognized by the car?). Indeed on the fourth push the locks clicked open.

Answer (score 2):

Older Honda keyfobs have a US quarter sized circle on the back with a groove in it. Stick a quarter (or your equivalently sized currency) in the groove and use it like a screwdriver. It will probably have an arrow on it, but if not anti-clockwise is the correct way to turn it. It will turn about ¼ of the way around and then you can pop it out (slap it against your palm if it's a bit stuck). The newer ones that are integrated with the key itself have a small screw on the back instead of a coin-sized slot (probably what you have if you've got a 2013 Accord).

Either way it probably contains a CR2025 (in US markets, at least) battery which you can then replace.

[image: Newer Honda keyfob being opened]